# How would one readLines from a gzip file in r?

Tags: r

I need to read lines in small batches (say 100 at a time) from a gzip file **which is a text file that has been compressed using gzip**. I use small batches because each line is extremely long.

However I am unable to that with something like this (I think the buffer is not updated):

```
in.con <- gzfile("somefile.txt.gz")
for (i in 1:100000) {
  chunk <- readLines(in.con,n = 100)
  # if you inspect chunk in each loop step, say with a print
  # you will find that chunk updates once or twice and then
  # keeps printing the same data.
}
close(in.con)
```

How do I accomplish something similar?

NOTES:

1. For small files this will work.
2. You will need a very large file and when you try to read it multiple times -- you will see that the chunk variable will not update
3. I think it is because an underlying scan is not reliable on a gzip file
4. The i variable is just to limit the loop -- i is not needed to be referenced
5. Some comments seem to be saying that the code will not work with a text file -- I'm posting results that show otherwise:

.

```
in.con <- file("some.file.txt", "r", blocking = FALSE)
while(TRUE) {
  chunk <- readLines(in.con,n = 2)
  if (length(chunk)==0) break;
  print(chunk)
}
close(in.con)
```

resulting in the output:

```
[1] "1" "2"
[1] "3" "4"
[1] "5" "6"
[1] "7" "8"
[1] "9"  "10"
```

My version information is:

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin15.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.1                         
year           2017                        
month          06                          
day            30                          
svn rev        72865                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
nickname       Single Candle
```

Comment: I was surprised to read that gz files have "lines". I thought they were just one big long stream.

Comment: The file is a text file compressed to a gzip file -- will update the question

Comment: @42- updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend using the combination of `ireadLines` and `nextElem` functions from the [`iterators`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iterators/index.html) package. There may be something else in `base` R, but `iterators` are what you need here.

Comment: I was able to read a gzip file with essentially the same code.  What is not working for you?

Comment: @G5W -- the buffer does not update -- I think the reason is that there are problems running scan on a gzip file -- which kinda makes sense

Comment: I see your added Notes.  I only tested on a small file.

Comment: Your `readLines` call never actually references the loop variable `i`

Comment: @thelatemail -- the i variable is just to limit the loop -- readLines regularly reads using scans i is not needed to be referenced

Comment: @thelatemail -- I don't think so Readlines if reading from a normal file continues reading from where it left off -- so it will read 1st 100 lines then next 100 lines and so fort

Comment: No it doesn't.  Not sure why you think it would do that.

Comment: @RichScriven I can double check -- but I have code running which uses that property -- when I ask it to instead read a gzipped file -- the code starts failing -- but I'll double check

Comment: @RichScriven -- I just posted code which shows the code running where successive readLines calls cause the pointer to advance

Comment: There's a mention of a bugfix to readLines in the [R-devel NEWS](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html); possibly related to what you're experiencing.

Comment: At the moment the `chunk` symbol will get repeatedly overwritten because there is no indexing on hte LHS of the assignment in the loop. Perhaps it should be `chunk[i:(i+99)] <- ...`

Comment: @42- hi, thanks, but I want chunk to get re-written with *new* data -- the problem is that when I print it out it has the same data with I do it with a gzipped file

Comment: @42- I added some comments to the code to address your concern -- thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug in `gzfile()`. For large files, if no `open` parameter is specified, it will read the same line over and over again.

```
> incon <- gzfile(zfile)
> readLines(incon,1)
[1] First line
> readLines(incon,1)
[1] First line
```

Even with the `open` parameter specified, it just causes an error instead.

```
> incon <- gzfile(zfile,open="r")
> line <- readLines(incon,1)
Warning message:
In readLines(incon, 1) :
  seek on a gzfile connection returned an internal error
```

**Solution**: As a workaround, one can instead use a regular `file()` connection in binary read mode and wrap it inside a `gzcon()`:

```
> incon <- gzcon(file(zfile,open="rb"))
> readLines(incon,1)
[1] First line
> readLines(incon,1)
[1] Second line
```

Comment: `gzfile()` is working for me now (R 4.1.0). Must've been a fix at some point.

Comment: At least for me R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt) still has a bug